# check whether a number conforms to the template 'ddd-dd-dddd'

Tags: java, boolean

The question is:

- Add a static method `boolean isValidNumber(String aNumber)`.
- Check whether the number conforms to the template 'ddd-dd-dddd',
  where every 'd' in the template stands for a digit and the '-' for a
  '-' character.

Can please anybody give a hint how to do it?

Comment: Hint: You could use regexps.

Comment: If it has `-` in it, it's not a number.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the `String` `matches` method to compare against a regular expression `String`.

```
 return aNumber.matches("\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\d\\d");
```

Comment: Could simplify the pattern to "\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}"

Comment: That shortens the pattern, I wouldn't say it simplifies it though - especially for someone new to regex like the OP seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
public static boolean isValidNumber(String aNumber) {
    if (aNumber.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")) {
        // Match found
        return true;
    } 
    // Not a valid number
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @Bhushan: Modified the post. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do like this

```
public boolean isValidNumber(String aNumber){
     return aNumber.matches("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this Regular Expression for your particular Sequence

```
^[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{4}$
```

this definitely helps you.

```
public class Sample 
{

        public static void main(String ar[])
{
      String aNumber= "254-58-3698";
       isValidNumber(aNumber);

}

public static Boolean isValidNumber(String aNumber)
{


      String pattern = "^[0-9]{3}\\-[0-9]{2}\\-[0-9]{4}$";

      // Create a Pattern object
      Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

      // Now create matcher object.
      Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
      if (m.find( )) {
         System.out.println("Number has Matched");  
return true;       
      } else {
         System.out.println("NO MATCH");
return false;
      }

}
}
```

output:

```
Number has Matched
```

Comment: I tried in my local system and gave the answer here..whatever the code i provided absolutely satisfies your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pre-built Pattern if you call this method a lot.

```
static final Pattern DDD_DD_DDD = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}");

public static boolean isDDD_DD_DDDD(String text) {
    return DDD_DD_DDD.matcher(text).matches();
}

public static void main(String... ignored) {
    for(String text: "Hello, 123-45-6789, 111-22-3333, 11-222-3333".split(", ")) {
        System.out.println(text+" is valid: "+isDDD_DD_DDDD(text));
    }
}
```

prints

```
Hello is valid: false
123-45-6789 is valid: true
111-22-3333 is valid: true
11-222-3333 is valid: false
```